# Comparing Two Distributions of Human Estimated Probabilities

Tags: probability, distributions, kullback-leibler

I have a two distributions of human-estimated (subjective) probabilities. Namely, let's say I have a group of meteorologists and a group of laypeople. Each person in either group estimates `p(x)` as the probability it will rain tomorrow.

I want to compare the group of estimated `p(x)`'s from the meteorologists with the estimated `p(x)`'s from the laypeople to see how similar they are. Can I do that simply using a method that compares two distributions (i.e. KL Divergence, JS Divergence)?

I'm a bit confused because the distributions of interest aren't probability distributions in the classic sense that they are probabilities of some set of outcomes for event `X=rain tomorrow`. Instead, I have a probability distribution over probabilities of some outcome for event `X`.

Should I think about this the same way regardless? I'm not a statistician so please let me know if I'm completely off!

Comment: "see how similar they are." <- what exactly do you want to know from "similarity"? Mean? A t-test might get you by. Absolute shape of distribution? Then you'll probably need something like KS. Do you care if they are right or not?

Comment: I'm looking for more than just the mean, so thinking KS. I do care if they're right or not, but don't have a ground truth to compare it against. Do I just assume one group or the other is correct?

Comment: KS can be quite sensitive if your sample size is large (statistically significant, but not practically significant). I recommend either just plotting the histogram and visualizing the difference or doing a difference of means t-test.

Comment: I agree with @TrynnaDoStat. Definitely plot the two distributions. A graphical approach will tell you far more about how the two groups differ than a single number from a KS test.

Comment: "Do I just assume one group or the other is correct?" - no, as far as I can tell you currently have no way of assessing this. I think you'll need to collect data to test if they are right, and then do two more separate analyses: 1) how good is group 1 at predicting the weather 2) how good is group 2 at predicting the weather

Comment: Okay that all makes sense, thank you! To the original question though, if I wanted to quantify it using a t-test for example, can I just treat both sets of data as probability distributions and compare them?

Comment: You don't need to "treat" them as anything, really - they're just numbers. And then you compare those numbers via a statistical test, e.g. the t-test. Note: t-test actually might not be appropriate if you have a small-ish sample size and the data is very skewed, or multimodal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Divergence tests can be quite sensitive if your sample size is large (statistical significance being different from practical significance). When comparing two distributions, I prefer to overlay histograms for the two distributions in a plot. This lets you know how the distributions are different and how meaningful the differences are.

If you want something more formal and more scalable, I suggest a difference in means t-test. A difference in means implies a difference in distributions, but will be less sensitive than divergence tests like a KS test (there are infinite ways distributions can be different).